# How to add Page Border using pylatex?

Tags: python, pylatex

I am using pylatex in python to generate PDFs. I want to add a Page border in the generated PDF but I am not able to do so. I didn't found any reference for adding border in the pylatex documentation. Is there any way that can work?
Here are the geometry options for Document class:

```
geometry_options = {
    "head": "40pt",
    "margin": "0.5in",
    "bottom": "0.6in",
    "includeheadfoot": True
}
doc = Document(geometry_options=geometry_options)
```

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: What kind of page border do you want? Like just a line around the page?

Comment: yeah, just a thick line around the page.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have posted this questions and now after some research I found its solution too.

There are many packages to add page border in a latex document using various packages.

Following are the steps that one can follow:

- Identify the package you want to use for your latex document.The one I used is *memoir* class and especially its *showtrims* function.
- After deciding the desired package, you can use **NoEscape()** function to execute raw latex commands in python.For example, NoEscape(r'\trimFrame')
- The last step will be to append this object returned by NoEscape() to the *doc* class.

Here is a code snippet- (Hope it helps!!)

```
doc = Document(documentclass='memoir',document_options=['10pt','a4paper','showtrims'],
                            geometry_options=geometry_options, lmodern = True)

new_comm1 = NoEscape(r'\trimFrame')
doc.append(new_comm1)
new_comm2 = NoEscape(r'\settrimmedsize{286mm}{198mm}{*}')
doc.append(new_comm2)
new_comm3 = NoEscape(r'\settrims{6mm}{6mm}')
doc.append(new_comm3)
```